# get value from next php file on previous php file

Tags: php, dynamic, getvalue

I have 2 file previous.php and next.php. I am calling next.php in previous.php, that time it loads the data but I want to access one variable in next.php in previous.php. I am new to php. Guide me regarding the same.

Comment: assign variable to  session  And call it where you need.

Comment: can you give sample code?

Comment: **Assign to session** 
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myValue']=$variable; 
?>
**use where you want to get variable value**
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
?>
use session_start(); before echoin or print tags.or simply place it at the starting of the page

Comment: but I want second php value in first. By using above code I can pass from first to second but I want exactly opposite.